# Draw a line between 2 zip code on US map in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to draw a straight line connecting 2 zip code in the US. So far I've only been able to plot points of each zip code in the US, but can't draw the line between them

Here is what my data look like. I am trying to draw 8 points on the US map and connect them, with 4 lines. I tried using zip.plot but it would only point points, not drawing a line

```
df1 <- data.frame(trip = c(1,2,3,4), zip1 = c(55803,87112,55107,66006), zip2=c(12909,93703,12205,78210))

df1
  trip  zip1  zip2
1    1 55803 12909
2    2 87112 93703
3    3 55107 12205
4    4 66006 78210
```

Comment: Please show your code for drawing the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [code](https://rdrr.io/cran/muRL/src/R/zip.plot.R) for `zip.plot` function, and you'll see it is straightforward. It will merge your zip code data with longitude and latitude data from `data(zips)`. You'll notice it will plot points, but no function to connect them, and it doesn't return points plotted.

You could adapt a similar function that meets your needs. If you include `library(muRL)` you can load zip data by `data(zips)`.  After plotting the points, you can add lines to connect them based on `trip` variable.

For example, create a new function `zip.plot.new`:

```
library(muRL)
data(zips)

zip.plot.new <- function(data, map.type = "state", ...){
  data.z <- merge(data, zips[,c("zip", "lat", "lon")], by.x = "zip", by.y = "zip", all.x = TRUE)
  maps::map(map.type, ...)
  points(data.z$lon, data.z$lat, cex = 1, col = "black", pch = 20)
  mapply(lines, split(data.z$lon, data.z$trip), split(data.z$lat, data.z$trip))
}
```

This includes `mapply(lines...` to connect points by `trip`.

Then, you can use your data frame, convert to longer form, and call this new function:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("zip_"), names_to = c(".value", "group"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  zip.plot.new(.)
```

[image: zip code plot]

Note that zip code `12909` was not matched in the data (appears not valid?).

**Data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(trip = c(1,2,3,4), 
                  zip_1 = c("55803","87112","55107","66006"), 
                  zip_2 = c("12909","93703","12205","78210"))
```

**Edit**: Here's a `ggplot` version:

```
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

MainStates <- map_data("state")

point_data <- df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("zip_"), names_to = c(".value", "group"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(zip = factor(zip, levels = levels(zips$zip))) %>%
  left_join(zips) 

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=MainStates, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color = "black", fill = "white") +
  geom_point(data = point_data, aes(x = lon, y = lat, group = trip)) +
  geom_line(data = point_data, aes(x = lon, y = lat, group = trip)) +
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  theme_nothing()
```